# 1D data passed to a transformer while using scikit-learn Column Transformer in Python

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

I'm using Column Transformer to perform preprocess and regression of a data set with mixed type of data. My label here is customers' response.

```
Train_df = pd.read_csv("/Users/apple/Documents/Training.csv")

print(Train_df.info())
```

here is the info

```
ata columns (total 20 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   ID            6815 non-null   int64  
 1   response      6815 non-null   object 
 2   IL1           6810 non-null   object 
 3   IL2           6728 non-null   object 
 4   IL3           6706 non-null   object 
 5   IL4           6289 non-null   object 
 6   CIL1          1670 non-null   object 
 7   CIL2          1646 non-null   object 
 8   CIL3          1506 non-null   object 
 9   CLI4          323 non-null    object 
 10  prime         6815 non-null   object 
 11  score1        5946 non-null   float64
 12  score2        2566 non-null   float64
 13  score3        2566 non-null   float64
 14  score4        2566 non-null   float64
 15  score5        2566 non-null   float64
 16  contact_type  6815 non-null   object 
 17  day           6815 non-null   int64  
 18  hour          6815 non-null   int64  
 19  device        6815 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(5), int64(3), object(12)
```

then I created a pipeline and run the data set through,

```
# create pipeline
# 'score1', 'score2', 'score3', 'score4', 'score5'
num_proc = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'), StandardScaler())

cat_proc = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='Not specified'),
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))

# Categorical: 'IL1', 'IL2', 'IL3', 'IL4', 'CIL1', 'CIL2', 'CIL3', 'CLI4', 'contact_type', 'prime'
preprocessor = make_column_transformer((num_proc, ('score1', 'score2', 'score3', 'score4', 'score5')),
                                       (cat_proc, 'prime', 'IL1'))
clf = make_pipeline(preprocessor, LogisticRegression())

X = Train_df.drop('response', axis=1)
y = Train_df[['response']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print("\tF1: %1.3f\n" % f1_score(y_test, y_pred, pos_label=1, average='micro'))
```

However, I got error after `clf.fit(X_train, y_train)` saying:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['1' '1' '1' ... '1' '0' '0'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError: 1D data passed to a transformer that expects 2D data. Try to specify the column selection as a list of one item instead of a scalar.
```

I have tried using `y = Train_df[['response']]` , `y = Train_df['response']`, either of them worked. Really don't know how to fix it.

Please help, thank you guys soo much!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the shape of the `y` variable here. You need to change it to a format of (n,1) i.e. a 2D array.

Use  `Train_df['response'].values.reshape(-1, 1)` instead of `Train_df['response']`
OR
Use `Train_df[['response']].values` instead of `Train_df[['response']]`